# Netbeans 8.0.2 Simple 2D Drawing

Tags: netbeans, jframe, jpanel, 2d, paintcomponent

Having trouble getting started with Java 2D using Netbeans 8.0.2. Would really appreciate if someone could post some very basic code for just a frame with a panel and a simple shape within.

I've been through so many tutorials, overridden the `paintcomponent()`, `super.paintcomponent()` etc. but really not sure how or what actually invokes this method, as it isn't getting invoked in my code :(

```
package guitest2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class TablePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public TablePanel() {
    initComponents();
    this.setSize(50, 50);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}        
}
```

---

```
package guitest2;

public class TableFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public TableFrame() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 529, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 393, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TableFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TableFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }               
}
```

---

```
package guitest2;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GUITest2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   TableFrame tf = new TableFrame();
   tf.setTitle("BJ");
   tf.setSize(1200,800);
   tf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   TablePanel p = new TablePanel();
   tf.setVisible(true);
   tf.add(p);

 }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that is not working to show what you tried.

Comment: "it isn't getting invoked in my code", but where is your code? Post your code or explain what you have tried.

Comment: @Noob999 : You have two `public static void main(String[] args) {` in your project. Put content of one to the other and delete this `main ...` .

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple code for drawing an oval on `JPanel` within a `Frame`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Test extends JFrame
{
public Test ()
{
    setSize (300,300);
    JPanel panel=new JPanel (){
        @Override
        public void paint (Graphics g){
            g.setColor (Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
        }
    };
    add(panel);
    setVisible (true);
}


public static void main (String args[]){
    new Test();
 }
}
```